# Restarting SuperVisor with code changes

Tags: django, supervisord

I am running a django project with Gunicorn and Nginx with Supervisor. Everything worked fine but when i made some changes to the code it is not recognized by the supervisor and still it reads the old codes. Can you please help me. I tried to restart supervisorctl, it didnt work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're talking about python code changes, just *use* `supervisorctl`.

```
supervisorctl restart gunicorn (or whatever you called this)
```

If you're talking about supervisor configuration changes, use `supervisorctl reread` before starting your supervisor startup script via `supervisorctl start foo`

Comment: It's not working for me :( I'm using socket and not runserver for django.

Comment: This solution is not working for me either.

Answer (score 1):

"You can gracefully reload your application in Gunicorn by sending **HUP** signal: `$ kill -HUP masterpid`", http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/faq.html

For example, `pkill -HUP gunicorn`

"Sending **HUP** signal to the Master Gunicorn process -- Reload the configuration, start the new worker processes with a new configuration and gracefully shutdown older workers.", http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/signals.html